# MediaWiki fails to show Ambox

Tags: mediawiki

I am writing you about the use of *Template:Ambox* in MediaWiki.

I have a version 1.28 hosted MediWiki installation that works well apparently at everything, but I can't get the boxes explain here https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Template:Ambox to work properly.

As a test I implemented in this page http://www.lucamauri.net/wikitrek/index.php?title=Pasticci the following code:

```
{{ambox
| type       = notice
| text       = Text for a big box, for the top of articles.
| smalltext  = Text for the top of article sections.
}}
```

and I expected a nice box to show up. Instead I simply see the text `Template:Ambox` shown at the top of the page.
It seems like this template is not defined in MediaWiki, but, as far as I understood, this is built-in and in all examples I saw it seems it should work out-of-the-box.

I guess I miss something basic here, but it really escapes me: any help you might provide will be appreciated.

Thanks

Luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrarily to what I originally thought, the AMBox template is **not** part of a standard MediaWiki installation.
To make it works it is necessary to:

1. If not already installed, install Scribunto extension as explained here https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto
2. Export the template using the export page https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:Export and manually adding the page `Template:Ambox` in the field
3. Import the resulting XML file in your MediaWiki installation via the `Special:Import` page

Then the Template will be available in your Wiki to use as explained in the MediaWiki website mentioned above